# Deploy node.js application to nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a node.js backend application running on port 1337 and i want to deploy it to my nginx server so i can get access to my backend from another computer and other netwroks.
i tried this in sites_availables and i enabled this configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name x.x.x.x(my server adrress);

    location /node {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

then i restarted nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

now i'm trying to reach `x.x.x.x/node` through my browser and i get  501 bad getaway.

Comment: What are you seeing in the nginx error and access logs?

Comment: there is no errors

Comment: And on your server if you run `curl http://localhost:1337`  what do you get?

Comment: yes its running perfectly

Comment: What about `curl http://localhost:1337/node`? I wonder if it is also trying to pass the `/node` part of the path from your nginx config

Comment: `curl http://localhost:1337/node` returns **error Cannot get node**

Answer (score 0):

The reverse proxy pipe from nginx to node is being broken because your path in the nginx config `/node` does not exist on your node application. You either need to implement that route, or do a rewrite to have nginx rewrite the path when proxying (check out this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url)

Comment: sure it will work because i implemented this route in my application.